# Finding correlated or comoving stocks

Tags: database, r, statistics, finance, quantitative-finance

I have a table of daily closing stock prices and commodity prices such as Gold, Oil, etc. I want to find what stocks move closely with another stock or a commodity.

Where do I start to do this type of analysis - I know java, SQL, python, perl, and a little bit of R.

Willing to buy and learn new tools like Matlab if necessary.

Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

This is not a homework question.

Thanks..

Comment: Better for stackexchange (statistics site); you should learn about statistical tools first before deciding what computational tools to use ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The technique you are looking for is called [cointegration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cointegration). Language is not important at all when computing cointegration of two time series so use whatever you are comfortable with.

I disagree with other responses that computation is not a problem. It is a huge problem to be able to compute potentially billions of cointegration coefficients between different time series. Using a highly optimized library is critical. However [this article](http://quanttrader.info/public/testForCoint.html) on cointegration testing in R should get you started.

Also checkout quant.stackexchange.com for more info on quantitative finance.

Comment: I didn't mean computation wasn't a problem, just that you should generally decide what you want to before deciding how to do it ...

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

http://www.sectorspdr.com/correlation/

http://www.etfscreen.com/corr.php

http://correlate.googlelabs.com/faq

https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1027/correlation-and-cointegration-similarities-differences-relationships/1038#1038

Answer (score 1):

> Where do I start to do this type of analysis

If I were you, I'd start by [searching Google Scholar for the word "comovement"](http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&q=comovement). Not everything that turns up is directly relevant, but there's quite a lot of stuff that is relevant.

By looking through the papers and googling some more, you should get a clearer picture of what types of statistical methods to learn.

I agree with Ben Bolker that computational tools are not the main issue at this point.